# UNIQUE constraint failed: mytable.hostName

Tags: python, sqlite, primary-key

I have created my own table called `mytable` in sqlite and want to capture content of a list of my hosts and write them into table. I can get content of pages with `python-requests` but while reaching to a host the following error occurs:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: mytable.hostName
```

Is this a problem with my table while creating it? I am creating the table like so:

```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (host CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, content TEXT);
```

## UPDATE

I removed my db completely and run my code again. but there is also the same error....

Comment: You try to insert the same name twice. It has to be unique in every row

Comment: I removed my db completely and run my code again. but there is also the same error....

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (host CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, content TEXT);
```

`PRIMARY KEY` has to be `UNIQUE`. You probably try to insert the same key twice like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(host, content) 
VALUES ('a', 'some text');
-- OK

INSERT INTO mytable(host, content) 
VALUES ('a', 'some text 2');
-- Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: mytable.host
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/42950/1/0)**</kbd>

Before you insert data you should check if it's existed already.

Comment: my hostnames are unique. I don't know why I see the ERROR :(

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to insert the same hostname which is unique 'Primary key).

Check your hostNames before inserting them into the table, you can't insert the same hostname twice